# C# Listview is not drawing the ListView SubItems on linux but works on windows

Tags: c#, linux, listview, mono, raspbian

I am creating a C# .NET Mono application to read logs in from a text file and display them in a listview. The logs are stored in JSON format so they can be parsed easily and be displayed as subitems in the listview.

[Picture of the working ListView run on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwBce.jpg)

My application is working correctly when I run the application on windows, however when I run it on the raspbian OS using mono none of the items in the listview are shown. I know that the logs are being read correctly from the text file on both Windows & Linux, as I have logged them to the console for debugging purposes. I have also confirmed that the logs have been copied into the ListViewItem "eachRow" correctly by logging it to the console as well.

I am hoping to find the problem that is causing the ListView Items to not be displayed when run on Raspbian. Due to the fact that I have the data stored correctly all the way up until it is added to the listview, I believe my problem is with the redrawing of the screen/listview.

This is the code I am using to Add each JSON item to the listview.

```
private void AddLogsToScreen()
    {
        //Create a copy of the current logList Stack
        LogMutex.WaitOne();
        Stack<string[]> logListCopy = new Stack<string[]>(new Stack<string[]>(LogList));
        Console.WriteLine("LLC: " + string.Join(" , ", logListCopy.Peek()));
        LogMutex.ReleaseMutex();

        if (HUBsLogsListView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            HUBsLogsListView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invoke Begin Update");
                HUBsLogsListView.BeginUpdate();

            }));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Begin Update");
            HUBsLogsListView.BeginUpdate();
        }

        var allItemsToAdd = new List<ListViewItem>();

        int totalLogs = logListCopy.Count;
        for (int logNum = 0; logNum < totalLogs; logNum++)
        {
            string[] log = logListCopy.Pop();
            string[] deepLogCopy = new string[8];

            // Copy to avoid messing up original
            log.CopyTo(deepLogCopy, 0);

            deepLogCopy[2] = DateTime.Parse(log[2]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy, hh:mm:ss tt");
            ListViewItem eachRow = new ListViewItem(deepLogCopy);
            Console.WriteLine("ListViewItem eachRow: " + eachRow.SubItems[0] + " , " + eachRow.SubItems[1] + " , " + eachRow.SubItems[2] + " , " + eachRow.SubItems[3] + " , " + eachRow.SubItems[4] + " , " + eachRow.SubItems[5] + " , " + eachRow.SubItems[6] + " , " + eachRow.SubItems[7]);
            if (deepLogCopy[4] == "3") //Warning
            {
                eachRow.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (deepLogCopy[4] == "4")  //Error
            {
                eachRow.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            allItemsToAdd.Add(eachRow);
        }

        if (HUBsLogsListView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            HUBsLogsListView.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                ListView.ListViewItemCollection lvic = new ListView.ListViewItemCollection(HUBsLogsListView);
                lvic.AddRange(allItemsToAdd.ToArray());
                HUBsLogsListView.EndUpdate();
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            ListView.ListViewItemCollection lvic = new ListView.ListViewItemCollection(HUBsLogsListView);
            lvic.AddRange(allItemsToAdd.ToArray());
            HUBsLogsListView.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
```

I can't come up with a reason why this function is acting differently, with the same files, on Windows compared to running on Linux using mono. I am not as experienced writing .NET programs using mono, so any and all help is appreciated.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `InvokeRequired` ?

Comment: I am using InvokeRequired because I am calling this function from two different locations, and one of them is in a seperate thread from the main GUI thread. @Franck